# How to add url in avaudioplayer in swift

Tags: ios, swift

i just want to ask on how to play audio using avAudion using url link..

and im getting error bad request.. can someone help me?

i already tried using avplayer but it is not suitable for me.. though it is working but.. i kinda prefer to use avaudioplayer

```
    let mp3URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3")
    do {
        // 2
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: mp3URL as URL)
        audioPlayer.play()
        // 3
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateAudioProgressView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        progressView.setProgress(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime/audioPlayer.duration), animated: false)
    }
    catch {
            print("An error occurred while trying to extract audio file")
    }
```

Comment: FYI - Don't use `NSURL` in Swift, use `URL`.

Comment: still getting bad request sir..

Comment: so i change 

let mp3URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3") 

to

let mp3URL = URL(fileURLWithPath:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3") 
but still getting bad request

Comment: My comment wasn't meant as a solution, hence the "FYI".

Answer (score 2):

According to [the AVAudioPlayer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer), if you want to play audio over the internet (that's not already downloaded to disk or memory) you should use [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer).

The docs describe AVAudioPlayer as

> An audio player that provides playback of audio data from a file or memory.

A little further down, in the overview section, emphasis added:

> Use this class for audio playback **unless you are playing audio captured from a network stream** or require very low I/O latency.

---

#### Notes

1. You can get some more information from the runtime by accessing the error object that is thrown when the connection fails. Change `catch {` to `catch let error {` and then you can log out the error as part of your message, like so:

```
catch let error{
    print("An error occurred while trying to extract audio file: \(error)")
}
```

2. When I run your sample code in Xcode playgrounds with the change noted above, I see the following:

> An error occurred while trying to extract audio file: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"

3. Notice the error's `Domain` and `Code`. [Pasting that error into Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=NSOSStatusErrorDomain+Code%3D2003334207&oq=NSOSStatusErrorDomain+Code%3D2003334207) yields some results that indicate that the URL might not be resolving correctly. (Indeed, clicking on that mp3 link shows a bad access error message.)

The first result is [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32278436/224988) with a similar issues. The second one is an [Apple Developer Forum post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5278) which has some more information.

Let's try to change the URL to a publicly accessible sample mp3 file. (I found [this one](https://sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3) by searching the web for "test mp3 file" on Google.)

4. You'll want to change `NSURL` to `URL`, and instead of `fileURLWithPath`, you're going to want to use another initializer. (Say, `string:`.)
5. Whenever you see `contentsOf...:` in a media or file API, there's a good chance it expects data or a file, to the exclusion of a network stream. Similarly, when you see an initializer or method that takes a `fileURL...`, the system expects to be pointing to a local resource, not a network URL.

Comment: FYI - you don't need the `let error`, just } catch { print(error) }`.

Comment: i already get it.. thanks sire for the help.. so over all i did was wrong :D :D .. bdw thank u guys

Answer (score -3):

```
if let mp3URL = URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3"){
        // do s.t
}
```

Anyway, you should know the basics of ios

Comment: still getting bad request