# AVAudioPlayer NSOSStatusErrorDomain error

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

As you may see, I'm trying to play audio obtained from a url. Where is the mistake?

The error seems to suggest that the audio from the url is not good...

```
//let play_url = "https://opus-server.herokuapp.com/asd.wav"
let play_url = "http://www.largesound.com/ashborytour/sound/brobob.mp3"
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {

    let url = URL(string: play_url)!

    do {

        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        audioPlayer?.play()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

I expect AVAudioPlayer to play the audio. Instead, there is an error printed: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play local audio file with AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278436/play-local-audio-file-with-avaudioplayer)

Comment: That question is related to how a local file is played, not from the web.

Comment: Have you added APP Transport Security Settings in Info.plist?

Comment: I just found the Answer of your Problem.....

Comment: No, the problem is not solved; I have already did that